# Curl of page with russian language

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I m getting encoding problem when doing curl using php of this page that is in russian language https://web.archive.org/web/20060403041216/http://inostranets.ru:80/

Here below the code that I m using :

```
$url="https://web.archive.org/web/20060403041216/http://inostranets.ru:80/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'waybackmachinedownloader');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

As result I m getting caracters similar to this: 
"ÂÍÅ ÊÎÍÊÓÐÅÍÖÈÈ – ÑÊÀÇÎ×ÍÛÉ ÑÈÍÃÀÏÓÐ
Òóðîïåðàòîð «ÄÅÎ» ïðèãëàøàåò Âàñ ïîñåòèòü"

Please check image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T6E4.png)

Comment: $utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "Windows-1251 (CP1251)");

Comment: No, it's not fixed. all caracters become question mark like this "?????????". I think the problem is with curl request

Comment: Definitely looks like an encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, but I think I need to request the correct encoding when doing the curl request.
I tried this but still didn't works : 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251",
  ));

Answer (score 2):

The page you're trying to parse is `windows-1251` encoded.
To tell the browser you're outputting `windows-1251`, you can use:

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');` ,

i.e.:

```
$url="https://web.archive.org/web/20060403041216/http://inostranets.ru:80/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'waybackmachinedownloader');
$html = curl_exec($ch);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
print $html;
```

---

Update:

To save the `$html` to a file use:

```
file_put_contents("curl_russian.html", $html);
```

**Note:**

When you open the `html` file, make sure you select `Text Encoding` to `Cyrillic Windows` on your browser.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks pedro.
But I want to write the content in a file. I m using this function but it never works : function write_file($url,$content){
 $myfile = fopen($url, "w");
 if($content){
  fwrite($myfile, $content);
 }
 fclose($myfile);
}

Comment: I'll have a look

Comment: I have tried it.. It's displayed correctly in the browser but it have wrong encoding in the file (example:"Èíîñòðàíåö"). I have found the problem.. I just have to encode the output like this header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251'); instead of $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "Windows-1251 (CP1251)");  Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I just have to encode the output like this:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "Windows-1251");
```

instead of:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "Windows-1251 (CP1251)");
```